# Как вернуть файл с сервера

Tags: golang, http

Как вернуть файл с сревера? Как я понял его надо записать в `ResponseWriter`, но как это сделать не могу понять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может это не совсем в стили GO, но работать будет:

```
func renderFile(w http.ResponseWriter, filename string) {
  fmt.Println("Read request: " + filename)
  file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Cann't open file: " + filename)      
   else {
      w.Write(file)
   }    
}
```